# Convert hover custom Navbar to Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Am a bit new to jQuery so please bear with me. I have this navbar menu that drops down on hover. Everything is working perfectly but my plan is to change the hover dropdown into a click and also hide the dropdowns when the outside html is clicked. I am not using any framework.

```
<ul class="tc-navigation">
  <li class="active">
    <a href="home.php">HOME</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a id="er">SERVICES</a>
    <ul>
      <li class="round"><a id="err">Transportation<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a>
        <ul>
          <li class="round"><a href="bus.php">Bus</a></li>
          <li class="round"><a href="taxi.php">Taxi</a></li>
          <li class="round"><a href="air.php">Air</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="round"><a href="car_rental_agencies.php">Car Rental Agencies</a></li>
      <li class="round"><a href="driving_licence.php">Driving Licence</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a id="er">ABOUT US</a>
    <ul>
      <li class="round"><a href="about_us.php">Who We are</a></li>
      <li class="round"><a href="our_vision.php">Our Vision</a></li>
      <li class="round"><a href="photo_gallery.php">Photo Gallery</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="round"><a href="contact.php">CONTACT</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
.tc-navigation li>ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  top: 120%;
  border-top: 2px solid;
  border-radius: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 190px;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  background: #fff;
  z-index: 10;
}

.tc-navigation li ul li {
  float: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
}

.tc-navigation li ul li:last-child {
  border: 0;
}

.tc-navigation li ul li a {
  width: 100%;
  color: #444;
  padding: 15px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  text-align: center;
}

.tc-navigation li:hover>ul {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  top: 100%;
}

.tc-navigation li ul li a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}

.tc-navigation li ul li a:hover i {
  color: #fff;
}

.tc-navigation li ul li a i {
  color: #666;
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 50%;
  margin: -7px 0 0;
}


/* Sub Menu */

.tc-navigation li>ul li ul {
  left: 110%;
  top: 0!important;
}

.tc-navigation li ul li:hover>ul {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  left: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Alright, Take a look on my menu**

```js
$('#cssmenu li.active').addClass('open').children('ul').show();
$('#cssmenu li.has-sub>a').on('click', function(){
  $(this).removeAttr('href');
  var element = $(this).parent('li');
  if (element.hasClass('open')) {
    element.removeClass('open');
    element.find('li').removeClass('open');
    element.find('ul').slideUp(200);
  } else {
    element.addClass('open');
    element.children('ul').slideDown(200);
    element.siblings('li').children('ul').slideUp(200);
    element.siblings('li').removeClass('open');
    element.siblings('li').find('li').removeClass('open');
    element.siblings('li').find('ul').slideUp(200);
  }
});
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,200);
#cssmenu,
#cssmenu ul,
#cssmenu ul li,
#cssmenu ul li a {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 1;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#cssmenu {
  width: 220px;
  font-family: Raleway, sans-serif;
  color: #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu ul ul {
  display: none;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.active > ul {
  display: block;
}
.align-right {
  float: right;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a {
  padding: 16px 22px;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 2;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  background: #bb0e0e;
  -webkit-transition: color .2s ease;
  -o-transition: color .2s ease;
  transition: color .2s ease;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a:hover {
  color: #d8f3f0;
}
#cssmenu ul > li.has-sub > a:after {
  position: absolute;
  right: 26px;
  top: 19px;
  z-index: 5;
  display: block;
  height: 10px;
  width: 2px;
  background: #ffffff;
  content: "";
  -webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
}
#cssmenu ul > li.has-sub > a:before {
  position: absolute;
  right: 22px;
  top: 23px;
  display: block;
  width: 10px;
  height: 2px;
  background: #ffffff;
  content: "";
  -webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
}
#cssmenu ul > li.has-sub.open > a:after,
#cssmenu ul > li.has-sub.open > a:before {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
#cssmenu ul ul li a {
  padding: 14px 22px;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 2;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ddd;
  background: #49505a;
  -webkit-transition: color .2s ease;
  -o-transition: color .2s ease;
  transition: color .2s ease;
}
#cssmenu ul ul ul li a {
  padding-left: 32px;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}
#cssmenu ul ul > li.has-sub > a:after {
  top: 16px;
  right: 26px;
  background: #ddd;
}
#cssmenu ul ul > li.has-sub > a:before {
  top: 20px;
  background: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<html lang="ru" dir="ltr">
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>

<!-- Icon Library -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="cssmenu">
  <ul>
     <li><a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-home"></i> Home</a></li>
     <li class="has-sub"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-bars"></i> Services</a>
        <ul>
           <li class="has-sub"><a href="#">Transportation</a>
              <ul>
                 <li><a href="#">Bus</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Taxi</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Air</a></li>
              </ul>
           </li>
           <li><a href="#">Car Rental Agencies</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Driving Licence</a></li>
        </ul>
     </li>
     <li class="has-sub"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-cog"></i> Abut us</a>
        <ul>
           <li><a href="#">Who We are</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Our Vision</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Photo Gallery</a></li>
        </ul>
     </li>
     <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-phone"></i> Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're currently using the `:hover` state in the CSS to set different rules for certain DOM elements.  CSS doesn't directly respond to click events (except for the `:active` state for links and buttons, which doesn't really help you here); so the easiest way to convert that to click events would be to have those click events toggle a CSS class on the element, which can then be used in the CSS exactly the same way you're currently using `:hover`.

```js
$('.tc-navigation > li').on("click", function(e) {
  $(this).toggleClass('showSubmenu');
  $(this).siblings().removeClass('showSubmenu'); // prevent two submenus from being "open" at the same time
  return false; // keep the event from bubbling 
});


// Hide menus when clicking outside them.  Might be preferable
// to set this only when a submenu is opened, but for now
// I'mm just brute-forcing it on the entire page:
$(document).on('click', function(){
  $('.tc-navigation > li').removeClass('showSubmenu')
});
```

```css
#container {position:relative}
body {background-color:#CCC}
.tc-navigation li>ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  top: 120%;
  border-top: 2px solid;
  border-radius: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 190px;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  background: #fff;
  z-index: 10;
}

.tc-navigation li ul li {
  float: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
}

.tc-navigation li ul li:last-child {
  border: 0;
}

.tc-navigation li ul li a {
  width: 100%;
  color: #444;
  padding: 15px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Changing this selector  from li:hover to li.showSubmenu; the rest of the CSS is as in the original: */
.tc-navigation li.showSubmenu>ul{
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  top: 100%;
}

.tc-navigation li ul li a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}

.tc-navigation li ul li a:hover i {
  color: #fff;
}

.tc-navigation li ul li a i {
  color: #666;
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 50%;
  margin: -7px 0 0;
}


/* Sub Menu */

.tc-navigation li>ul li ul {
  left: 110%;
  top: 0!important;
}

.tc-navigation li ul li:hover>ul {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  left: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
<ul class="tc-navigation">
  <li class="active">
    <a href="home.php">HOME</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a id="er">SERVICES</a>
    <ul>
      <li class="round"><a id="err">Transportation<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a>
        <ul>
          <li class="round"><a href="bus.php">Bus</a></li>
          <li class="round"><a href="taxi.php">Taxi</a></li>
          <li class="round"><a href="air.php">Air</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="round"><a href="car_rental_agencies.php">Car Rental Agencies</a></li>
      <li class="round"><a href="driving_licence.php">Driving License</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a id="er">ABOUT US</a>
    <ul>
      <li class="round"><a href="about_us.php">Who We are</a></li>
      <li class="round"><a href="our_vision.php">Our Vision</a></li>
      <li class="round"><a href="photo_gallery.php">Photo Gallery</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="round"><a href="contact.php">CONTACT</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

(I had to add a container element to keep the submenus from falling offscreen; the positioning is still not quite right, I assume because your CSS depends on other page elements not shown here, but it's close enough to demonstrate the idea.  Other than that the only change to your CSS was the one line where `li:hover` was changed to `li.showSubmenu`.)